# How to Run a Standard Two-Sample t-test when given delta and not the two means

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, two-sample

I am trying to find the p-value to test a null hypothesis using a Standard Two-Sample t-Test. Usually I would use

```
tsum.test(mu1, sd1, n1, mu2, sd2, n2, 
          conf.level=0.95, var.equal=TRUE)
```

but I am not given mu1 or mu2 or sd1 or sd2. Instead, I am given mean difference d=2.7 and standard deviation sdd=15.9 and n is 171 matched pairs. What code do I use to find the Standard Two-Sample t-Test?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that this is a paired test? A paired test is not the same as a two-sample test, despite there seeming to be two groups. A paired test is a one-sample test on the differences between pairs. The distinction will affect your results.

Comment: It is not clear to me which I am supposed to do, which I know doesn't help for context. We can assume I am looking for a paired one sample test

Comment: Splendid, so then what are the equations for such a test? (Remember that a paired test turns out to be, at least in some sense, a one-sample test, so if you have the one-sample test equations, you have what you need.)

Comment: tsum.test(2.7,15.9,171,var.equal = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)
is the code I think I would use

Comment: But what are the equations?